# Solve $y'=e^{x^2}y$ (with $3$ terms only) in using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Solve $y'=e^{x^2}y$ (with $3$ terms only) in using power series.

I know that $e^{x^2}=\sum_{n \geq0} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$, but I don't know how to find the coefficients $a_n$ in considering $y=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$.

To help me understand how to solve this question, is that someone could at least just find the recurrence relation to this differential equation and show the procedure of his argument?

Comment: I'm assuming that we are expanding about $x_0 = 0$. Assume a power series solution of the form $y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$, plug it into the PDE and derive the recurrence relation for $a_n$. This will get you the solution. You will need to use the Cauchy product to simplify the term on the RHS.

Comment: I already know everything you're telling me. However, the factor $e^{x^2}$ blend me a bit. I also would need someone to display its result that I can compare with what I did.

Comment: Like I said you will need the Cauchy product to compute RHS. There is no easy way around it (that I am aware of).

Comment: Ok, but could you expand on what you do?

Comment: Even computing the first few terms of the RHS by using the Cauchy product should be enough to allow you to write down an expression for $a_n$.

Comment: Okay, what do you have so far for the LHS? and the RHS? Please edit your post so I can see your work so far.

Comment: Do you know about the Cauchy product? and how to use it?

Comment: Yes, I know that

Comment: Okay, give me the first five nonzero terms on the RHS. What is on the LHS? Can you then compute $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $a_4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the given ODE is linear we may assume $y(0)=1$. Therefore we can write
$$y(x)=1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+?x^4\ ,$$
whereby the question mark represents some convergent power series whose coefficients we don't care about. In the same vein we have
$$y'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+?x^3,\qquad e^{x^2}=1+x^2+?x^4\ .$$
We now have to compare coefficients in
$$\eqalign{a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+?x^3&=\bigl(1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+?x^4\bigr)\bigl(1+x^2+?x^4\bigr)\cr
&=1+a_1x+(1+a_2)x^2+?x^3\ .\cr}$$
Note that only "safe" coefficients may be used for the comparison; that's why we have to carry the ?s along in the computation..

Answer (score 1):

From
$y'
=e^{x^2}y
$,
$e^{x^2}
=y'/y
=(\ln(y))'
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\ln y
&=c+\int e^{x^2}dx\\
&=c+\int \sum_{n \geq0} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx\\
&=c+ \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac1{n!} \int x^{2n}dx\\
&=c+ \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac1{n!}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
&=c+ \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\\
\text{so}\\
y
&=e^c \exp\left( \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\right)\\
&=e^c \left(1+\left( \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\right)
+\frac12\left( \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\right)^2 
+\frac16\left( \sum_{n \geq0}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\right)^3 
+...\right)\\
&=e^c \left(1+\left( x+ \frac13 x^3+...\right)
+\frac12\left( x+ \frac13 x^3+...\right)^2 
+\frac16\left( x+...\right)^3 
+...\right)\\
&=e^c \left(1+\left( x+ \frac13 x^3+...\right)
+\frac12\left( x^2+...\right) 
+\frac16\left( x^3+...\right) 
+...\right)\\
&=e^c \left(1+ x+ \frac12 x^2+\frac12 x^3+...\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: $\int x^{2n}dx$ is $\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, not $\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n+1}$. I only spotted this because of the discrepancy with Christian Blatter's answer, which gives $e^c(1+x+\frac12 x^2+\frac12 x^3+\cdots)$.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected and upvoted.